# How mix Spring Validator and JSR 303

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation, spring-validator

I want to perform a validation both by using annotations and Spring Validator.

**Product.java**

```
public class Product {
    private int id;
    @NotNull(message = "cannot be null")
    private String desc;

    // getters and setters
}
```

**ProductValidator.java**

```
public class ProductValidator implements Validator {
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return Product.class.equals(aClass);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        Product p = (Product) obj;
        if (p.getId() <= 0) {
            errors.rejectValue("id", "id must be positive");
        }
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Product product = new Product();

    DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(product);
    binder.addValidators(new ProductValidator());
    binder.validate();

    System.out.println(binder.getBindingResult());
}
```

I was expecting two errors in the output but I get only the Spring Validator's one.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataBinder validators are initially empty. [Implementation](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/validation/DataBinder.java)

Try adding JSR 303 validator, something like this:

```
 ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();

 DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(product);
 binder.addValidators(new ProductValidator());
 binder.addValidators(new SpringValidatorAdapter(factory.getValidator()));
 binder.validate();
```

Comment: This works as exected, thanks. Do you know if there's a specific order of execution of these validators? Is there a way to customize the order? Thanks.

Comment: There are executed in order of defining, because they are added in array list. Check lines 867-874 in above link. On line 162, there is initialisation of list.

Comment: Is there a way to short-circuit the validators as soon as one find some errors?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to stop executing other validators in list, as soon as one finds some errors? For that you will need to extend DataBinder class and override validate method or if you set your validators at the head of the list, you can throw RuntimeException (or its subclass) after you reject value in validator. Then you catch exception when you are calling validate method.